# How to find the average time from an array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, array, average

I am referencing a list which has a lot of data in the form of the elapsed time of a process and I'm trying to convert it to a format where I can find the average amount of elapsed time.

The data looks something like this:

```
ElapsedTime
0 hours, 1 minutes, 14 seconds
0 hours, 16 minutes, 2 seconds
0 hours, 4 minutes, 0 seconds
0 hours, 11 minutes, 59 seconds
```

So I have the above data Imported into a variable and extract the numerical data using this formula:

```
$ElapsedHours, $ElapsedMinutes, $ElapsedSeconds = $TimeElapsed -split ', ' -split ' ' | Select -Index 0,2,4
```

From there I assign the values to a variable and an instance of New-TimeSpan:

```
$ElapsedTimeSpanObject = New-TimeSpan -Hours $ElapsedHours -Minutes $ElapsedMinutes -Seconds -$ElapsedSeconds
```

This is the part that gets tricky for me. The two above examples of code are all taking place within a Foreach loop and I've already created a blank array. After the timespan object is created, it is inserted into the array and looks at the next ElapsedTime value.

**I want to find the average of the total array.**

When I execute the current code I have for trying to find the Average I get an error. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$ElapsedTimespanCollection | Measure-Object -Average
```

Executing the above code gives me this error for each object in the array:

> Measure-Object : Input object "00:02:44" is not numeric.
>   At line:1 char:30
>   + $ElapsedTimespanCollection | Measure-Object -Average
>   +                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (00:02:44:TimeSpan) [Measure-Object], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonNumericInputObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand

So how do I go about converting or formatting these measurements of time into something I can check against for their average?

Comment: Are you showing all of the times in the array that you want? I'm just confused where the input 00:02:44 comes from.

Comment: The 00:02:44 comes from an example of the type of error messages I am getting with the above code. I don't have that particular snippet in the ElapsedTime data but you get the picture. The ElapsedTime data is an example of the data I am working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the data to a valid time type and then use the `.TotalSeconds` property to convert the `hh:mm:ss` string to a time format you can then get numeric total seconds, etc. There are additional **methods** and **properties** you should be able to utilize here to help.

```
$ElapsedHours, $ElapsedMinutes, $ElapsedSeconds = $TimeElapsed -split ', ' -split ' ' | Select -Index 0,2,4
$ElapsedTimeSpanObject = New-TimeSpan -Hours $ElapsedHours -Minutes $ElapsedMinutes -Seconds -$ElapsedSeconds

## -- $ElapsedTimespanCollection = "00:02:44"
$ElapsedTimespanCollection = [TimeSpan]$ElapsedTimespanCollection 
$ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds
```

---

### Further Resources

- [TimeSpan Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)

  > ### **Properties**
  >
  > - **Seconds:** Gets the seconds component of the time interval represented by the current TimeSpan structure.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > ### **Methods**
  >
  > - **Duration():** Returns a new TimeSpan object whose value is the absolute value of the current TimeSpan object.

Comment: cyborgcommando0 - You are obviously going to have to calculate the sum of the seconds, then divide that by the number of objects in the set to get the average seconds, and then convert that back to a duration. For your immediately problem, I showed example of how to convert from string `00:00:00` to a time type to then be able to convert to other numeric data type and such. Happy to help further if you ask, so let me know.

Comment: I've never used `Measure-Object -Average` with an array of `hh:mm:ss` strings or time duration for that matter but you may already know how to get `Measure-Object -Average` to bring back an average for the array set or whatever. I have to step away but will check in later.

Comment: You got me on the right track. For some reason I was thinking the TotalSeconds method was only Seconds and not minutes or hours and I'm going to blame my script for poisoning my mind.  
 
I changed the code inserting each TimeSpan Object to this:
`$ElapsedTimespanCollection += $ElapsedTimeSpanObject.TotalSeconds`  
 
Then I just did the below code and it gives me what I need.  
 
`$FindElapsedTimeSpanAverage = ($ElapsedTimespanCollection | Measure-Object -Average).Average`  
 
`$ElapsedTimeSpanAverageObject = New-TimeSpan -Seconds $FindElapsedTimeSpanAverage`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This script uses a RegEx with (capture groups) to extract hours, minuts and seconds from an inline csv with a here string.
It creates a PSCustomObject from all the time data

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\03\SU_1336282.ps1
$TimeLapsed = @"
ElapsedTime
0 hours, 1 minutes, 14 seconds
0 hours, 16 minutes, 2 seconds
0 hours, 4 minutes, 0 seconds
0 hours, 11 minutes, 59 seconds
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'

$Elapsed = ForEach($row in $TimeLapsed) {
    if ($row -match '(?<HH>\d+) hours, (?<mm>\d+) minutes, (?<ss>\d+) seconds'){
        $TotalSecs = (3600 * $Matches.HH) +
                     (  60 * $Matches.mm) +
                        [int]$Matches.ss
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Hour     = [int]$Matches.HH
            Minute   = [int]$Matches.mm
            Seconds  = [int]$Matches.ss
            TotalSecs= $TotalSecs
        }
    }
}
$Elapsed
$Elapsed | Measure TotalSecs -Average -Sum -MAx -Min|ft *
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SU_1336282.ps1

Hour Minute Seconds TotalSecs
---- ------ ------- ---------
   0      1      14        74
   0     16       2       962
   0      4       0       240
   0     11      59       719



Count Average  Sum Maximum Minimum Property
----- -------  --- ------- ------- --------
    4  498,75 1995     962      74 TotalSecs
```